# JasperReports's scriptlet "beforeReportInit()" , what does it do?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jasper-reports, scriptlet

I am using *JasperReports* **scriptlet --> beforeReportInit()** and I want to call a **Stored Procedure** in oracle database so that a **temporary table** will be populated with data which i can then **use to fill the report**.

In other words I'm trying to achieve some oracle reports **after parameter form trigger** actions. How can I do this or what am i missing here?

```
/* before report is initialized */
public void beforeReportInit() throws JRScriptletException {

    // gathering report connection
    Connection conn = (Connection) this
            .getParameterValue("REPORT_CONNECTION");

    // calling stored procedure execution method.
    boolean status = executeStoredProcedures(conn,
            this.getParameterValue("P_NIC").toString(),
            Integer.valueOf(this.getParameterValue("P_TYPE").toString()));

    // if fails
    if (!status) {
        // setting the error on variable to display on the report
        this.setVariableValue("ERROR_LOG", "PRE-REPORT TRIGGER FAILURE");
    }
}
```